# continue with next iteration if foreach loop takes too long

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I have a for each loop that pulls queries out of a table with queries.
The loop then executes each query and writes the results to a table.
This works like a charm. I even implemented error-handling for when a query could not be executed (if it for example does have syntax-errors).

But sometimes executing a query will take forever, for example a query with a cross join without proper predicament.

Now I would like to be able to set a max duration on the execution of a query. So that a query  will be stopped after an x amount of minutes (if it did not finish by then).
The loop should then continue with the next query.
In other words, an iteration should never take longer than X minutes, after that it should continue with the next iteration.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Comment: Please provide your query and execution plan in `sqlplan` format...

Comment: SQL executes queries sequentially,it cant do parallel query execution,you may need to go for c# and execute queries in parallel ,i believe ssis also has ability to execute child containers parallely

Comment: @devart At this moment there are 462 queries. Queries may be added and removed. So I need to plan for queries that are technically sound but that will run forever. I do not think that a sqlplan will help since all these queries  have only one thing in common: the SELECT. The FROM, WHERE and additional components can all be different.

Comment: @TheGameiswar I do not understand your suggestion: I want them to run sequentially since they all insert into the same table but I want to stop a loop after a specified amount of time and continue with the next. What has parallel execution to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **CANT** set a timeout for the query on the server.

Either you create a client app where you can set a **[timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx)** for the sql command

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
         // Setting command timeout to 1 second
         command.CommandTimeout = 1;
         try {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
```

Or try this [**External Tool**](http://whoisactive.com) to monitor query and kill those process when time run out. As mentioned on **[dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66249/how-do-i-find-a-long-running-query-with-process-id-process-name-login-time-u/66261)**